# How can you change the color and line type of an individual line in a line plot on Jupyter Notebook when plotting the entire Dataframe at once?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, line-plot

I am trying to figure out how to change the line color and line type of an individual line after plotting an entire dataframe at once.

This is a snapshot of my dataframe:
[image: dataframe]

Then I used this to plot it:

```
df_month.plot(figsize=(15,10), linewidth = 3.5)
plt.xlabel('Months', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Average Precipitation (mm/d)', fontsize =19)
plt.title('Precipitation near Cape Scott Wind Farm', fontsize=22)
plt.savefig('CapeScott_precip.png')
```

And it resulted in this:

[image: graph]

So I am wondering how I can change just the 'WRF-GFS' line to a dashed black line? Any guidance will be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reset the index first:

```
df_plot = df_month.reset_index()
```

Loop through the columns to plot them, with different parameters for the 'WRF-GFS' column:

```
for col_name in df_plot.drop(columns='Datetime', axis=1).columns:
    if col_name == 'WRF-GFS':
        plt.plot(df_plot['Datetime'], df_plot[col_name], color='black', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3.5, label=col_name)
    else:
        plt.plot(df_plot['Datetime'], df_plot[col_name], linewidth=3.5, label=col_name)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Running this with some random data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df_plot = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_plot['Datetime'] = list(range(10))

for col_name in df_plot.drop(columns='Datetime', axis=1).columns.tolist():
    if col_name == 'B':
        plt.plot(df_plot['Datetime'], df_plot[col_name], color='black', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3.5, label=col_name)
    else:
        plt.plot(df_plot['Datetime'], df_plot[col_name], linewidth=3.5, label=col_name)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That gives me a KeyError: "['WRF-GFS'] not found in axis. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what does `df_month.columns` return?

Comment: Index(['WRF-GFS ', 'Herbert Island Station', 'Sartine Island Station', 'Solander Island Station', 'Quatsino Station'], dtype='object')

Comment: Oh your entire DataFrame is indexed? For convenience, you'll probably want to use `df_month.reset_index()` before passing it to `plt.plot()`. I'll edit my answer